# Работа БД Access и DLL

Tags: база-данных, delphi, delphi-7, access, ado

Есть самописная программа, которая перестает нормально функционировать после установки на компьютер windows 10.

Это DLL, которая была написана в 2010 году что-то делает, и возвращает значения, в этом промежутке пытается приконнектиться к БД Access, что по итогу выливается в данное окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа работает отлично на windows 7.

Версия access, что на win 7, что на 8.1, что на win 10 стоит одинаковая.
Исходники от DLL к сожалению недоступны и нет возможности посмотреть какая строка подключения используется в коде dll.

Comment: UDL-файл мб поискать надо поблизости?

Comment: мб и надо, только его нет в папке проекта.

Comment: И подключение идёт через connection string, а не через Data link(во всех подключениях в проекте). И мало вероятно, что dll будет использовать вручную созданный файл UDL хотя бы потому, что этого файла нет в проекте

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, дело не в версии операционной системы, а в наличии DSN, через который пытается работать ваша DLL. Если компьютер с Windows 7 ещё доступен, то попробуйте проверить, какие "Источники данных ODBC" были созданы ранее, и какие доступны сейчас (в Windows 10 - нажмите поиск и наберите "Источники данных...").
Важно то, что источники данных бывают Пользовательские и Системные - проверьте обе вкладки.
Кроме того, 32- и 64-разрядные приложения используют разные источники - разрядность приложения "Источники данных ODBC", используемого для настройки, и вашей DLL должны совпадать.

Comment: Настройки идентичные

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился достаточно просто. Достаточно было просто от имени администратора запускать программу.